# What are the key differences between the movie and TV versions of Quatermass and the Pit?

Tags: quatermass-and-the-pit

The Hammer movie version of *Quatermass and the Pit* was released in the mid 1960s and was one of Hammer's best movies. But the original script was broadcast live on the BBC in the 1950s in six 30 minute episodes (and we are very lucky anybody recorded it: the first two series of Quatermass did not survive in their entirety).

What are the key differences between the 3 hour TV version and the much shorter Hammer movie?

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, the stories are essentially the same, with the capsule being discovered, the Martian remains, the telepathic 'sightings' of the ghost Martians, the links to the devil via the aliens' appearance and the inscriptions on the craft.

The only significant difference I can recall is the ending. In the original BBC series, Quatermass attempts to destroy the Martian apparition with a heavy iron chain which is grounded. He misses, and the soldier helping him sacrifices himself to complete the task.

In the Hammer version, Quatermass climbs into a crane and swings the arm around into the apparition, shorting it out and ending the threat.

Comment: Wow - this must surely be the longest interval between question and answer on the site.

Comment: I had to think about it.

Comment: I just re-viewed both versions and some of your details are wrong. Rooney is the saviour in both versions (climbing the crane in the Movie and throwing the iron chain in the TV series).

Comment: Oh, really? Feel free to edit my answer then - thanks for doing the research.